# Parse oData response in Java

Tags: java, parsing, odata

I am creating a Http request to access `OData` services. I am getting the response but I don't know how to parse the response into a String objects so that I can add them to a `ArrayList`.

Here is my code:

```
protected List<StatusResponse> doInBackground(Void... params)
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        // Execute HTTP Post Request

        mResponseList = new ArrayList<StatusResponse>();
        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();

        HttpGet httpget =  new HttpGet(myOdataQueryUrl);

        try 
        {

            HttpResponse responsenext = httpclient.execute(httpget);
            HttpEntity entitynext = responsenext.getEntity();
            AddedResult= EntityUtils.toString(entitynext);

             jsonArray = new JSONArray(AddedResult);
            for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++)
            {
                JSONObject menuObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);

                String createdBy =  menuObject.getString("CreatedBy");
                String comment =  menuObject.getString("Comment");
                String location =  menuObject.getString("Location");
                String slot =   menuObject.getString("Slot");
                String reachingAt =   menuObject.getString("StartTime");
                String lunch =  menuObject.getString("Lunch");

                mResponseList.add(new StatusResponse(createdBy, comment, location, slot, reachingAt, lunch));
            }

            }


        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }



                return mResponseList;
    }
```

I get this response:--

```
{
  "odata.metadata":"mysite/odata/$metadata#OStatus","value":[
    {
      "StatusId":2151,"Location":"Office","Slot":"Running late","StartTime":"2014-09-29T12:30:00","Comment":"-","Lunch":null,"CreatedBy":"","ModifiedBy":null,"Created":"2014-09-29T04:39:10.443","Modified":null
    }
  ]
}
```

I get the following error if I try to parse it like above:

```
Value {"value":[{"Created":"2014-09-29T04:39:10.443","Modified":null,"StatusId":2151,"ModifiedBy":null,"Slot":"Running late","CreatedBy":"","Comment":"-","Location":"Office","Lunch":null,"StartTime":"2014-09-29T12:30:00"}],"odata.metadata":"https:\/\/mySite\/odata\/$metadata#OStatus"} of type org.json.JSONObject cannot be converted to JSONArray
```

Comment: Looks like JSON, so use a JSON parser.

Comment: @nablex please see my edit code and error that I get

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're trying to convert a normal JSON object into a JSON Array.

It also seems that you're declaring that array to be a field in stead of a local variable to your method. Are you sure that is what you need?